# How to modify Permission for AppCatalog site in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

Anyone can help to modify admin permission to AppCatalog site after created the site. I have created a Appcatalog site but now my client told me to change the admin permission of that site and currently I am not the administrator of that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the SharePoint admin center-> sites-> Active Sites, select the AppCatalog site. In the ribbon click Permissions-> manage admins.

[image]